# Python Selenium - AttributeError : WebElement object has no attribute sendKeys

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I'm trying to pass through "ENTER" to a text field, using `Selenium` (Python). The text box requires that each phone number be entered on a new line, so it will look something like:

```
#Add the phone number#
Webelement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I've imported the following library:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

The problem I'm getting is that it fails with:

> AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendKeys'

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I've been searching for a solution, but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: The very first example in the [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) documentation should help.  Also, a google search for `python selenium sendkeys` provides all sorts of useful hints as to the problem ...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try using [`WebElement::send_keys()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) instead of `sendKeys` as below :-

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Webelement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: I think it should be `WebElement.send_keys()` insted of  `WebElement::send_keys()`