# What is correct way to set send keys when use selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I'm new python (programming). Currently working on a project to fill up forms using selenium and python.

So for everything seems okay. I successfully installed python 3.6, selenium on pycharm and chrome drive on my windows.

I try to open a website and fill the form using the script. The script opens the site but couldn't put the texts in the form.

I have been browsing stack overflow and googling for hours and anything doesn't work.

It shows error regarding sendkeys.

**Here's the full code**

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Replace below path with the absolute path
# to chromedriver in your computer
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\public\chromedriver.exe')


# Go to your page url
driver.get('https://www.website.com/')

# Get button you are going to click by its id ( also you could us find_element_by_css_selector to get element by css selector)
button_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('signup_email_link')
button_element.click()

input_element = driver.find_element_by_name("first_name")
input_element.sendkeys(ram)
```

**Here's the error code,**

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/My Projects/My scripts automate.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/My Projects/My scripts automate.py", line 22, in <module>
    input_element.sendkeys(ram)
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendkeys'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I even tried to replace the input_element with web_element but error continuous.

I use latest Python 3.6 version on pycharm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Selenium - AttributeError : WebElement object has no attribute sendKeys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521136/python-selenium-attributeerror-webelement-object-has-no-attribute-sendkeys)

Comment: No, it's different question bro

Comment: Does send_keys not work?

Comment: No, bro it doesn't

Comment: I've read the other parts.. It does work, you have a different error because of the undefined variable "ram". So therefore your original question was a duplicate..

Comment: Okay bro I will define ram. If it doesn't work. I will come again.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
input_element.send_keys(ram)
```

instead of

```
input_element.sendkeys(ram)
```

Comment: Thanks Sithling. but not working. Here's the error, C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/My Projects/My scripts automate.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/My Projects/My scripts automate.py", line 22, in <module>
    input_element.send_keys(ram)
NameError: name 'ram' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @Joel you need to define `ram`, looking at your code there is no mention of the `ram` variable.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `input_element.send_keys(ram)`.

[List of methods here.](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/.../selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mazjin.

Comment: Here's the error,                                                                                                               C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/My Projects/My scripts automate.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/My Projects/My scripts automate.py", line 22, in <module>
    input_element.send_keys(ram)
NameError: name 'ram' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: With the underscore included? 
Does it give a different error message?

Comment: @Joel you need to define `ram`, looking at your code there is no mention of the `ram` variable.

Comment: Ah, well you just need to set `ram` to a string containing whichever characters you need to send, or replace it with said string, ie.

`ram='some string'
input_element.ssend_keys(ram)`

or

`input_element.send_keys('some string'`

Comment: but that's a name

Comment: where is ram coming from? where do you initialise this?

Comment: If you want it to literally send the string 'ram', you need to tell it that it's a string using quotation marks like I've just done.

Comment: I'm new to programming. I never defined 'ram'. I will define to see whether works or not. Thanks guys.

Comment: No worries, make sure to accept @ProNinjaCat's answer above.

Comment: @mazjin i didn't make an answer for it, so best to accept yours i suppose